# Access nested value in json React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

```
"order":[
         { 
           "localId" : 2445,
           "tariff": {
              "tariffName": {
                   "nameRu": "Добро пожаловать",
                   "nameEn": "Welcome"
                             },
             ........
                      }
          }
       ]
```

This is my JSON. I want to access to "nameRu". How to do it inside my React Native app?
Currently, I am able to get "localId" in this way: 
`{order:localId}`

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {order:[
         { 
           localId : 2445,
           tariff: {
              tariffName: {
                   nameRu: "Добро пожаловать",
                   nameEn: "Welcome"
                             },
                      }
          }
       ]}
       console.log(obj.order[0].tariff.tariffName.nameRu)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this object destructing. [Reference](https://itnext.io/using-es6-to-destructure-nested-objects-in-javascript-avoid-undefined-errors-that-break-your-code-612ae67913e9)

```js
let d = {
  "order": [{
    "localId": 2445,
    "tariff": {
      "tariffName": {
        "nameRu": "Добро пожаловать",
        "nameEn": "Welcome"
      }
    }
  }]
};

// extract with variable name 
let [{
  tariff: {
    tariffName: {
      nameRu
    }
  }
}] = d.order;

// print 
console.log(nameRu);
```